# Function bugs out after first loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have this function which purpose is to change class of items inside a list in order, and then repeat. Using the suggestion of a member of SO, my code is as follows:

```
<ul class="display" id="imagens-home">
            <li class="invisivel"><img src="img/teste/lanche-1.jpg"/></li>
            <li class="invisivel"><img src="img/teste/lanche-2.jpg"/></li>
            <li class="invisivel"><img src="img/teste/lanche-3.jpg"/></li>
            <li class="invisivel"><img src="img/teste/lanche-4.jpg"/></li>
          </ul>
```

My function:

```
    var animationIn = 'animated fadeInLeft';
var animationOut = 'animated zoomOut';
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

function animate($items, idx) {
  if (idx >= $items.length) idx = 0; // no more items, stop animating

  var $current = $items.eq(idx);
  $current.removeClass('invisivel').addClass(animationIn).on(animationEnd, function() {
    $current.removeClass(animationIn).addClass(animationOut).on(animationEnd, function() {
      $current.removeClass(animationOut).addClass('invisivel');
      animate($items, idx + 1); // try animating the next item
    });
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
  animate($('#imagens-home>li'), 0);
});
```

The problem is that the code works as intended, iterating through the 4 images. However after this first loop, it doesn't fadeOut, and cuts right to the next image, skipping animations. This happens twice and then the code stops working. What might be the cause?

Comment: have you checked your console for any errors?

Comment: and you dont close the curly brace { of function animate()

Comment: You are binding new event on each recursive call, the older ones are still bound. Use `one` not `on` ( [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6Lo4qaf/) ) or set logic outside recursive method

Comment: The problem was indeed the `on`. Thanks!

Comment: @AthMav No, OP wants to call it on document ready.